# How to enumerate groups for a user in a multidomain environment

Tags: c#, .net, windows, pinvoke, directoryservices

Suppose you have a forest with two domains in your organization. In my case, each domain is defined in a server, so I have two domain controllers.

```
DOMAIN1
  group1
  user1
DOMAIN2
  group2
  user2

group1 members: user1, user2
group2 members: user1, user2
```

Is there a way to list the groups that **user1** belongs to, from a machine that is in the domain DOMAIN2? Using C# or WinAPI is valid for me.

---

**EDIT:** The WinAPI function [NetUserGetGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370653%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does not work for me since it does not work when it's executed to load user1's group in a machine that belongs to domain DOMAIN2.

I need something similar to [LookupAccountName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that is able to resolve cross-domain:

> If the name cannot be resolved on the local system, this function will
>   try to resolve the name using domain controllers trusted by the local
>   system.

Comment: NetUserGetGroups should work, you just have to specify a domain controller for DOMAIN1 as the target computer.  You can use NetGetDCName to find a suitable DC.  Failing that, you might need to query Active Directory explicitly.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663271%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for some options.  Personally, I've used the LDAP API to good effect for this sort of job, though only in a single-domain context.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 4.0, the [`System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace can help.
You create the connection to the domain using `PrincipalContext`, get the user using `UserPrincipal` and call the method `GetGroups`. I believe you can do it for all the required domains, providing you have appropriate permissions. This Code Project [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38344/Using-System-DirectoryServices-AccountManagement) shows some examples.